# Program exits even though while loop condition isn't met

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm really new to programming and have a slight issue: my program keeps exiting even though my while loop should continue.

It's supposed to be a two dimensional guessing game which is about half way done, but whenever I test run it it just exits as it's done even though I haven't guessed the right numbers.

I don't understand, this is a call for help.

```cs
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int y = 0;
            int x = 0;
            int ranX = random.Next(1, 4);
            int ranY = random.Next(1, 4);

            while (x != ranX && y != ranY)
            {
                int[,] shootingRange = new int[,]
                {
                    {0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0},
                    {0,0,0,0}
                };
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("    1   2   3   4");
                for (int a = 0; a < shootingRange.GetLength(0); a++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("  -----------------");
                    Console.Write(a + 1 + " ");
                    Console.Write("| ");

                    for (int b = 0; b < shootingRange.GetLength(1); b++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" " + " | ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(" ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("  -----------------");

                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Indicate new shot");
                Console.Write("X cordinate: ");
                x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (x > 4 || x < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Out of range");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                Console.Write("Y cordinate: ");
                y = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                if (y > 4 || y < 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Out of range");
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Well for one thing, your while loop will finish when *either* of your values are correct... you only keep going while *both* are wrong. Beyond that, it's hard to say without more details. Have you stepped through the code in the debugger? At what point does it not behave as you expect, and what is the program state at that point?

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to learn about a debugger and setting breakpoints

Comment: You should probably create a function to print your tableau.  Also, I don't think you really want to reinitialize that matrix to 0 for every loop.

Comment: Thank you all so much. Started yesterday so don't really know what I'm doing. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 3):

Test it a few more times and observe that it doesn't *always* do what you describe.  But it does do it *often*.  Why?

Because the loop only continues if both guesses are wrong:

```
while (x != ranX && y != ranY)
```

So if either guess is *right* then the loop terminates.  And with a 25% chance for each number there's a decent chance the user got *one* of them correct.

The loop should continue if *either* of the guesses are wrong:

```
while (x != ranX || y != ranY)
```

Or, if it semantically makes more sense to you, the loop should continue *unless* both guesses are right:

```
while (!(x == ranX && y == ranY))
```